# Tests result as successful, although errors are found during Tests

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, automated-tests, phantomjs, qunit

I have set up my test environment as described here with QunitJS + PhantomJS + GruntJS: http://jordankasper.com/blog/2013/04/automated-javascript-tests-using-grunt-phantomjs-and-qunit/

Everything works fine, but I have the problem that, my Grunt Task finishes without errors, although errors are found. This is crucial for my build process. Due to the Test results the build either fails or succeeds. But in my case the build always succeeds. Any Ideas why grunt doesn't exit with failure when errors found?

qunit Task of the grunt file:

```
module.exports = {

  services: {
    options: {
      urls: [
        'http://localhost:8000/tests/services.html'
      ],
      timeout: 20000,
      force: true
    }
  },

  gui: {
    options: {
      urls: [
        'http://localhost:8000/tests/gui.html'
      ],
      timeout: 20000,
      force: true
    }
  }

};
```

Output:

[image]

Please consider that I cant upload more info due to confidental issues.

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question to include your gruntfile and also the output you get from running Grunt?

Comment: hey dude, i cant upload my grunt file. But I assume that it is configured correctly. The tests would not be executed otherwhise.

Comment: Any reason you can't edit your question to include the gruntfile?  Too big?  Contains confidential info?  You don't have to upload it to some file hosting site somewhere, you can put the text of it in the question.

Comment: Both of the reasons my File is too big AND contains confidental data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking 'why does Grunt continue and when the tests fail?'  The answer is 'because you are asking it to'.

The [`force`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit#force) option controls whether the QUnit task fails if there are failing tests.  Setting it to `true` as you have done tells Grunt to continue even if there are failing tests. Try setting it to `false`, or removing it altogether as `false` is the default.

Comment: this did it :) thank you. you may have an answer for this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928672/qunitjs-tests-dont-start-phantomjs-timed-out-possibly-due-to-a-missing-qunit